# The product of the lengths of two line segments that belong to Newton line

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, elementary-proofs, polygons

I am looking for the proof of the following claim:

> Consider a family of [bicentric quadrilaterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral) with the same inradius length and the same distance between incenter and circumcenter. Denote by $P$ and $Q$ the midpoints of the diagonals, and by $I$ the incenter. Then, $|PI| \cdot |QI|$ has the same value for all quadrilaterals in the family.

[image]

The GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ax6g8fr3).

Comment: What is fixed except inradius?

Comment: A suggestion, using the $p,q$ method, since I haven't worked out the details.  One can assume that the quadrilateral has vertices $(0,0),(a,0),(p,q),(r,s)$.  The three conditions imposed (bicentricity, constant inradius) can be expressed as polynomial ones on $p,q,r,s,a$, as can the final identity.  One then uses Gröbner bases.  As usual, care must be taken when squaring up.

Comment: @FedorPetrov The distance between incenter and circumcenter. Also radius of circumscribed circle is the same for all quadrilaterals in the family because distance between incenter and circumcenter, inradius and radius of circumscribed circle are related by Fuss theorem.

Comment: All points $P$ and $Q$ lie on the same circle, so $-PI\cdot QI$ is just a power of a point $I$ in this circle.

Comment: @FedorBakharev How do you know that all $P$ and $Q$ lie on some circle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the incircle be the unit circle. Let $A'$, $B'$, $C'$, $D'$ be the points where this is tangent to $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$, and let them have coordinates $(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$, $(\cos \beta,\sin \beta)$, $(\cos \gamma, \sin \gamma)$ and $(\cos \delta, \sin \delta)$.

Then the quadrilateral $IA'BB'$ has two right angles, so $\angle A'BB' = \pi - \angle B'IA' = \pi - \beta + \alpha$. Likewise, the quadrilateral $IC'DD'$ has $\angle C'DD' = \pi - \delta + \beta$. But these two angles are opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral, so they sum to $\pi$. Thus $(\pi - \beta + \alpha) + (\pi - \delta + \beta) = \pi$, and $\delta = \pi + \alpha - \beta + \gamma$.

Now
$$A = \left(
\frac{\sin\alpha-\sin\delta}{\sin(\alpha-\delta)},
-\frac{\cos\alpha-\cos\delta}{\sin(\alpha-\delta)}
\right)$$
$$B = \left(
\frac{\sin\beta-\sin\alpha}{\sin(\beta-\alpha)},
-\frac{\cos\beta-\cos\alpha}{\sin(\beta-\alpha)}
\right)$$
$$C = \left(
\frac{\sin\gamma-\sin\beta}{\sin(\gamma-\beta)},
-\frac{\cos\gamma-\cos\beta}{\sin(\gamma-\beta)}
\right)$$
$$D = \left(
\frac{\sin\delta-\sin\gamma}{\sin(\delta-\gamma)},
-\frac{\cos\delta-\cos\gamma}{\sin(\delta-\gamma)}
\right)$$
Letting $\theta=\alpha-\beta$ and $\phi=\beta-\gamma$, we have:
$$|PI|^2=\frac14(A+C)\cdot(A+C)=\frac{1-\sin\theta\, \sin\phi}{(\sin\phi)^2}$$
$$|QI|^2=\frac14(B+D)\cdot(B+D)=\frac{1-\sin\theta\, \sin\phi}{(\sin\theta)^2}$$
And after finding the circumcenter $O$,
$$|IO|^2=\frac{1-\sin\theta\, \sin\phi}{(\sin\theta)^2(\sin\phi)^2}$$
This leads to $$|IO|^2=|PI||QI|+|PI|^2|QI|^2$$
or in unit-free terms
$$|IO|^2=|PI||QI|+|PI|^2|QI|^2/\text{inradius}^2$$
which establishes the claim.